# Webbrowser class DocumentComplete event not firing in class(not in WinForm)

Tags: vb.net, class, webbrowser-control

I am using `WebBrowser` class in class.
I am trying to add webbrowser_documentcomplete event handler but I found that event not firing. Please find below code I am using. This code working with an Windows Form but not in class.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Imports System.Threading

Public Class GoogleSearch

    Dim WithEvents WBBrowser As New Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

    Dim TimCount As New System.Timers.Timer()

    Sub New(ByVal SearchParameter As String, ByVal ResultPage As Integer)


        TimCount.Interval = 2000
        TimCount.Enabled = False
        AddHandler TimCount.Elapsed, AddressOf TimCount_Tick


        WBBrowser.Visible = True
        WBBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True

        AddHandler WBBrowser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WBBrowser_DocumentCompleted


        WBBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com", False)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TimCount_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Try
            TimCount.Enabled = False
'Some code goes here

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub WBBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Try
            If WBBrowser.ReadyState <> Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
                Return
            Else
                TimCount.Start()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature for your DocumentCompleted Event is:

```
    (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
```

Surprised the compiler didn't balk at you about that.